# How can I map the complete json data into my code? Right now I can only do it for one entry at a time

Tags: json, reactjs, mapping, state

```
export default class FetchData extends React.Component{
  state = {
    loading: true,
    currentPrice: null,
    oneDayChange: null,
    sevenDayChange: null
  };
```

//these are the three values i need to get from the json result

```
  async componentDidMount(){
    const url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxxx'
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const info = await response.json();
    this.setState({currentPrice:info.data[5].quote.USD.price})
    this.setState({oneDayChange:info.data[5].quote.USD.percent_change_24h});
    this.setState({sevenDayChange:info.data[5].quote.USD.percent_change_7d});
    console.log(info.data[5].id);
  }
```

//can only update states by giving array index of 1 entry

Comment: you want to map all data and store values in array state like you do for 1?

Comment: May be you can change your state structure like this :
```state = {
    loading: true,
cryptoCurrency: []
  };
``` 
and pass an array of object in cryptoCurrency

{
    currentPrice: number,
    oneDayChange: number,
    sevenDayChange: number
}

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
async componentDidMount(){
    ....
    const info = await response.json();

    const currentPrice = [];
    const oneDayChange = [];
    const sevenDayChange = [];

    info.data.map(item => {
      currentPrice.push(item.quote.USD.price);
      oneDayChange.push(item.quote.USD.percent_change_24h);
      sevenDayChange.push(item.quote.USD.ercent_change_7d);
    });

    this.setState({currentPrice, oneDayChange, sevenDayChange});
}
```

Comment: Hi, so any specific reason to put array in place of object (key value) ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple state changes might not be working as you might be trying to modify state object directly, below solution will replace state with new object copying all the old values and replacing mentioned properties.

**This should work**

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    const url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxxx'
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const [loading, newArray]
    const info = await response.json();
    const infoUSD = info.data[5].quote.USD;
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, state , {currentPrice: infoUSD.price, oneDayChange: infoUSD.percent_change_24h, sevenDayChange: infoUSD.percent_change_7d});
    console.log(info.data[5].id);
 }
```